# How can I debug a Flutter Web App on Safari using the inspector?

Tags: flutter, safari, flutter-web

I am using flutter to write a simple app, everything works fine on Android, iOS, and Chrome. (I've also tested on Firefox & Brave Browser, all's well).

However, on Safari (Mac & iOS), the flutter app gets stuck on the index.html file and does not load the PWA.

The error from the console on Safari Inspect

[image: The error from the console on Safari Inspect]

How can I know what the anonymous function in js_helper is, or what main.dart.js:57063 refers to?

1. Is there any way of building for web without minifying?
2. Has anybody encountered a scenario where everything works on all platforms except Safari?

Flutter Doctor
[image: Flutter Doctor]

Log from console when running on local server
[image]

Comment: There is [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/55323) for that

Answer (score 8):

debug for safari is not supported yet

but for anyone with the same problem you could solve it by running the app on release mode

```
flutter run -d chrome --release
```

after that open with the same port on safari and everything should be fine

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to  debug it directly on Safari, but if you just want to test your app in safari with localHost, you can use these steps :

1. Enable 'developer' menu in Safari from settings of Safari :

[image]

2. Then check on 'Disable Cross-Origin restrictions"

[image]

3. Now after running release version of web app in chrome, use same app's address in Safari, you will be able to test it. Ex. http://localhost:51155/

[image]

to run in release mode : `flutter run -d chrome --release`

Hope this helps!